# Piano MIDI Notes Issue

Tags: ios

I am trying to play MIDI Notes by loading CMP_GrandPiano.sf2 file but the problem is, it sounds same note (regardless of Octave notes) every time means it's not producing proper notes sound.Please can anyone help me to sort it out?

### Code:

```
id connectionToken = [deviceManager connectInput:source 
                                    error:error 
                                    eventHandler:^(MIKMIDISourceEndpoint *source, 
                                                   NSArray *command) { 
                            __strong MIKMIDIEndpointSynthesizer *strongSelf = weakSelf; 
                            [strongSelf handleMIDIMessages:commands]; 
                      }];
```

Method:

```
- (void)handleMIDIMessages:(NSArray *)commands { 
        for (MIKMIDICommand *command in commands) { 
              OSStatus err = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.instrumentUnit, 
                                                  command.statusByte, 
                                                  command.dataByte1, 
                                                  command.dataByte2,
                                                  0); 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Post some code please. How are you getting the MIDI notes (MIDI callback, some other way, etc?)

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am simply loading .sf2 file from document directory and set up every thing for Audio Unit.I am using MIKMIDI library for this.

Comment: Can you show the `connectInput: error: eventHandler:^(MIKMIDISourceEndpoint, NSArray` function block? Probably would help if we could see what you're doing in the callback function

Comment: id connectionToken = [deviceManager connectInput:source error:error eventHandler:^(MIKMIDISourceEndpoint *source, NSArray *commands) {
  __strong MIKMIDIEndpointSynthesizer *strongSelf = weakSelf;
  [strongSelf handleMIDIMessages:commands];
 }];

Comment: '- (void)handleMIDIMessages:(NSArray *)commands
{
    for (MIKMIDICommand *command in commands)
    {
        OSStatus err = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.instrumentUnit, command.statusByte, command.dataByte1, command.dataByte2,0);
     
    }
}'

Comment: Ok so I want you to print out what the command bytes are giving you. So in you for loop for the commands do - `NSLog(@"%@", command);`. We need to check what the MIDI data is saying, it might only be sending the same note for some reason (we don't know why yet).

Comment: Sure,I will print the command.Thanks for responses. :-)

Comment: @yun.cloud,I have printed out the command and i found its giving proper notes value but as i am experiencing only one type of sound hearable.Following is the print log :- command: 159 channel 0 note: 60 velocity: 127 ON
command: 159 channel 0 note: 60 velocity: 0   OFF
command: 159 channel 0 note: 72 velocity: 127 ON
command: 159 channel 0 note: 72 velocity: 0   OFF

Comment: So now my next question: Is `instrumentUnit` a MusicSynthesizer audio unit? Because ya it seems like that's the only handling of MIDI notes you're doing

Comment: Yes instrumentUnit is MIDISynthesizer audio unit.

Comment: I'm at a stop haha, I'll have to read more into MIDISynthesizer audio unit to help you more, sorry bout that

Comment: One more thing,when I tried to play MIDI notes by loading other sound font file so it ran all over fine.